# How to console.dir() on extendScript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I want to familiarize with the DOM in `extendScript` , I want to `console.log(certainObject)` or `console.dir(certainObject)` in order to check its properties.

There is a way to `console.log()` such as `$.writeln(certainVariable)` but that won't return the properties of that object.

I can use the `extendScript toolkit` but in the `Data Browser` I can't identify all the objects.

Going to the [documentation](https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/PlacedItem.html#jsobjref-placeditem) is confusing , for instance for this object `app.activeDocument.placedItems` it list certain properties , but a basic property such as the method `app.activeDocument.placedItems.add();` is not there.

Where does that method come from? Inheritance ? , How can I check this?.

Comment: Consider utilizing the [ExtendScript reflection interface](https://extendscript.docsforadobe.dev/extendscript-tools-features/extendscript-reflection-interface.html) for obtaining the properties and methods of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get all (?) properties of the object is just to loop through them and to print the result in the console:

```
var obj = app.selection[0];
var props = '';
for (var prop in obj) {
    try { props += prop + ' : ' + obj[prop] + '\n' }
    catch(e) { props += prop + ': ???\n' }
}
$.writeln(props.split('\n').sort().join('\n'));
```

Not sure if it's the best way, but I'm doing it sometimes. )

I saw the solution that does the same and put the result into a panel. It can be done quite easy if you know how to create a panel and to fill it with a text.

As for the methods... Well, I don't know the answer.

Comment: Amazing approach and really nice answer , with this methodology I we can get around the limitation of the Scripting Language in this regard , thank you!